# Problem with compiling/running a file in neovim

Tags: c++, neovim

When I try to run a file with Neovim it shows me this:

[image: this]

It doesn't allow me to type any input. How can I type some input using Neovim ?

This is my script for compiling:

```
g++ -static -DLOCAL -lm -s -x c++ -Wall -Wextra -O2 -std=c++17 -o $1 $1.cpp
```

This are my commands in Neovim for compiling and running a cpp file:

```
autocmd filetype cpp nnoremap <F9> :w <bar> !build.sh %:r <CR> 
autocmd filetype cpp nnoremap <F10> :!./%:r<CR>
```

Comment: What does `:!cat<Enter>`  do in your vim set up?

Comment: I don't know where to find that. This is my init.vim file : https://pastebin.com/3LwP9PZ4

Comment: You don't nered to *find* it, you need to *try* it.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWA18.png || https://i.stack.imgur.com/g71r8.png ; It doesn't do anything.

Comment: I see two thing: (1) you are on Windows (you need to mention what kind of setup you have) and (2) you are trying to do "competitive programming" (you should never do that). Anyway, if you cannot type in `:!cat` and see your input echoed back to you, then your vim setup seems broken. You can  try asking in https://vi.stackexchange.com